# java SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();

        String dateString = now.toString();
        System.out.println(" 1. " + dateString);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

        try {
            Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(" 2. " + parsed.toString());
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
        }

        System.out.println(" 3. " + format.format(now));
    }
```

print in console:

```
 1. Thu Feb 23 17:14:51 CET 2017
ERROR: Cannot parse "Thu Feb 23 17:14:51 CET 2017"
 3. jeu. févr. 23 05:14:51 CET 2017
```

instead of:

```
 1. Thu Feb 23 17:14:51 CET 2017
 2. Thu Feb 23 17:14:51 CET 2017
 3. jeu. févr. 23 05:14:51 CET 2017
```

Comment: Your no. 3 indicates your system locale is French, hence "Thu Feb" isn't recognized by the formatter as it expects French names only.

Comment: Bonjour, is there a reason why you are still using the old-fashioned classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? The new classes in `java.time` (since Java 8) have `toString` and `parse` methods that agree about the default format and locale, so will save you of a problem like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your default `Locale` is `FRENCH`, and since `SimpleDateFormat` uses it if you don't specify another one, you can't successfully parse english abreviations like `Thu` or `Feb`.

However, you can specify the use of the `ENGLISH` `Locale` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have run into one of the many diseases of the now out-dated `Date` class in Java.

The sound and easy fix is to change over to the Java 8 date and time classes. The new class that best corresponds to `Date` is `Instant`. With this class your code becomes:

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();

    String dateString = now.toString();
    System.out.println(" 1. " + dateString);

    try {
        Instant parsed = Instant.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(" 2. " + parsed.toString());
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
    }
```

I have left out `3.` from your example. Of course it is possible to format the `Instant` in about any way you could dream of, but if we just want the same output as from the `toString` method I don’t find it worth it for now. Rather I would like to show that for this case you don’t need a format at all. The code prints:

```
 1. 2017-02-23T17:07:19.775Z
 2. 2017-02-23T17:07:19.775Z
```

You notice that it prints the time in UTC. If you want your local time zone instead, just use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `Instant`. The rest of the code is exactly the same, but now output on my computer is:

```
 1. 2017-02-23T18:07:19.852+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
 2. 2017-02-23T18:07:19.852+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Of course it is possible to generate an error like the one you get from disagreeing locales also with the new classes. As far as I can see, you would have to explicitly specify disagreeing locales. So you don’t do it easily.